# UK Building Regulations Concerning Radiator Pipes in Walls

Tags: plumbing, repair, pipe, building-regulations

I had a builder install a wall cabinet in a new build. He hit a radiator pipe so I then called a plumber to fix the leak, who did so by disconnecting the relevant radiator from the system . The plumber also claimed that the plastic radiator pipe should never have been installed like it was; it's bending around the corner of a room instead of being just vertical or horizontal, and also crosses behind electrical wires. The plumber said this is 'illegal' and that if I contact my property developers they would be responsible for fixing the punctured pipe, rerouting them safely, reconnecting the radiator and patching the wall back up, whereas if I were to use him I would have to pay a few hundred.

However, I think the developers will say that it's my fault and not fix it, so if there is a buildings regulation breach or any strictly 'illegal' activity going on because of the piping being the way it is, I'd like to know for sure. The only regulation I could find was NHBC guidance that plastic pipes ought to have metal strips behind them so they can be detected, but that guidance hasn't been breached. Is it really a breach of regulations for the piping to be bent around the corner of a room and for it to cross over insulated electrical wires?